# Any other distro offer like Ubuntu Software Centre?

Tags: linux, package-management, software-installation, distribution-choice, yum

I want to know does any other linux disto offer anything close to Ubuntu Software Centre? Some of the features I like about it is A) Sandboxing B) Ability to search any of the libs/apps with screenshot(if any) and description. [ Been a while since using Ubuntu - I remember *this* description form when I was launched. And please DO NOT recommend Ubuntu :) ]

I am ok with using yum and apt-get. But for graphical package kit I am not that impressed with what Fedora/Opensuse have in PackageKit. Half of the time it updates and when you search for anything you hardly find them. Finally have to resort to yum.

So has any other linux distro got it better than Fedora and Opensuse?

Answer (score 3):

Mandriva used to be *the* distribution with a nice and user-friendly package management system. See [this page](http://wiki.mandriva.com/en/ControlCenter) for more info.

It was ahead of its time when it got out, but I think nowadays that Ubuntu Software Centre is way beyond others.

Answer (score 2):

Debian Squeeze has a software centre.